# Alternative source of "blackguard"

Tags: etymology

It occurred to me to wonder when I ran across a French reference to practices of the Inquisition; it mentioned that imprisonment was fully intended to be torture that had a strong beginning when a guard-blacksmith shackled the prisoner to the wall of his/her cell. Could this functionary have been the original blackguard? Not in French, of course, where the word would be something like *gardien-taillefer* and the word itself is *canaille*.

Comment: I *think* "the original question" addressed [the etymology of *blackguard*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18043/what-is-the-etymology-of-blackguard-does-this-british-sounding-word-have-subt)

Comment: Yes, it could be the source. Do you have any evidence though? Also, which word is 'gardien-taillefer' and the word itself 'canaille' in English? (it is not clear what you mean)

Comment: *Gardien-taillefer* is the guard-blacksmith: you can see "gard" (guard) and "fer" (iron=ferrous, ferrite) in it.

Comment: Can you provide the text and source of this "French reference"? Without these it is impossible to tell whether the proposed etymology aligns with the actual history of the word in English.

Comment: @Greycard, I've added some sources to *[What is the etymology of “blackguard”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18043/what-is-the-etymology-of-blackguard-does-this-british-sounding-word-have-subt/18280#18280)*.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this derivation is quite impossible.

1. The term "black guard" first emerges (according to *OED 1*) in the 1530s. Before the 1670s, every instance but one of "black guard" cited by *OED 1* refers to a company, not an individual, "black" by virtue of their dress or their villainy or their dirtiness. (The one exception, upon examination of the source, refers to a guard who is, in fact, black—a negro.)
2. In early use a *guard* watches over persons or places in order to defend them. The word is not used before the 19th century of an officer who watches over prisoners to prevent their escape—that is a *warder* or *keeper* or *gaoler*.
3. It is unlikely that such an office as "guard-blacksmith" existed. A blacksmith in a fortress/prison or military unit would not be numbered among the common warders or soldiers; for instance, in 1414 [William Merssh](http://books.google.com/books?id=W2jTtdISwMMC&pg=PT68&lpg=PT68&dq=blacksmith+%22Tower+of+London%22&source=bl&ots=4cBfBWtI44&sig=JyGMy7d_L_fDKpPw0E5wUpnhWOk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4lxWULykAeXkygHEt4DYBw&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=blacksmith%20%22Tower%20of%20London%22&f=false) was [*capitalis faber*](http://www.archive.org/stream/reignofhenryfift01wyliuoft/reignofhenryfift01wyliuoft_djvu.txt) at the Tower of London, a highly skilled craftsman, maintaining his own forge and directing his own operations, under the Clerk of the Works.
4. If such an officer existed, it is inconceivable that he would have been called a  *black* guard. A *smith* guard, perhaps, or an *iron* guard; but the smith is called a "blacksmith" only to distinguish him from a goldsmith or a silversmith, because he works in the *black* (dark) metal iron; in no other context does "black" refer to the smith's trade.

A point which may be advanced in favour of OP's derivation is three allusions to the "black guard of the Dominic Friars" in Foxe's *Acts and Monuments*, 1563— exactly when the phrase begins to be frequently encountered. One of these refers specifically to Dominic's preaching against the Albigenses and causing "many of them to be burnt; for the which he [...] was made patriarch of the black guard of the Dominic Friars."

But *black* here refers to the color of the Dominican habit, and *guard* is a collective, referring here and elsewhere in Foxe to the order's militancy. And for all Foxe's popularity over the following generations, nobody seems to pick the phrase up; Google Books finds no use of *black guard* from Foxe's day until 1700 which is not accommodated in *OED 1*'s uncontroversial account of the phrase's development from "royal or military kitchen staff" to "camp followers" to "street urchins/linkboys" to "criminal low-life".

The origin of *blackguard* is a little obscure, but not so obscure as *OED 1*'s admirable scholarly punctilio suggests, and not nearly obscure enough to accommodate this conjecture.

Answer (score -1):

The OED has quite a detailed etymological note which begins:

> The earliest uses apparently show simple phrasal uses, referring to a
>   person or group of people (contextually or habitually) dressed in
>   black or black in appearance, although many early uses also at least
>   play on figurative meanings of black.